# Which is my school level?

Tags: vocabulary

I was answering an american survey where the questions has been (badly?) translated in French and I had to answer to the question: "Quel est votre niveau scolaire ?" that I can translate to "Which is your school level?".
I wanted to answer "Master" but I've got an error saying the form was waiting a number value. I guess, even if the question has been translated in French, the form is expected an answer based on the US school system.

I made some research to find the equivalent grade level for a master degree but what I found wasn't satisfactory. Indeed, I found [two scales](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Education_in_the_United_States#/media/File:Education_in_the_United_States.svg): one from grade 1 to grade 12 but that only considers high school and before; one other for postsecondary education from grade 1 to grade 7.

Master degree is grade 5 but it is confusing with the other scales. So I answered 17 (12 + 5), am I right?

Comment: I think this should be asked at french.stackexchange.com This is a question of interpretation of a French phrase, not a English one.  But 17 is almost certainly wrong. However I don't know the French System well enough to be sure.

Comment: however it is possibly "4.3.3" in Canda: see  https://www23.statcan.gc.ca/imdb/p3VD_f.pl?Function=getVD&TVD=305734&CVD=305737&CPV=4.3.3&CST=07042016&CLV=4&MLV=4    4.3.3 - Maîtrise (plus haut niveau)
Cette catégorie comprend les titulaires d'une maîtrise décernée par un établissement conférant des grades universitaires. Elle comprend, par exemple, la maîtrise ès arts (M.A.), la maîtrise ès sciences (M.Sc.) ou la maîtrise en théologie (M.Th.). Cette catégorie exclut les titulaires d'un doctorat acquis

Comment: @JamesK I think this is a wrong translation of an English question. It was an American survey.

Comment: Then it would be pure speculation.  Are you sure this survey was not intended for children at school, and not for adults with Master's degrees?

Comment: @JamesK It was a survey about Covid-19 and you had to be at least 18 years old to participate to it.

Comment: Depends on how important the survey is to you.  If it is very important (eg for a visa applicaion or similar) then contact the survey writer.

Comment: Often a survey will present their own scale along with the question. Maybe the scale somehow got forgotten when making the translated version of the survey.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it appears to be too localized and based on a translation, not an original English-language source. It also seems like there's a problem with how the survey and response system were implemented.

Comment: @Em. It is from an English-language source. The translation in French is mine.

Comment: Isn't your question based on a French translation? Then what is the original English-language statement/question? What is your translation? If this post is based on the French question or on your translation (of that French question into English), then neither is the original English-language source. Even having the original might not make this on-topic (I'm not sure, depends).

Comment: @Em. My bad, you're right. I got all mixed up, sorry.

Comment: No problem. The other thing is that it seems like there's a problem with how the survey and response system were implemented (which is not an English language problem). If we had the original source, this would be much easier to answer (and/or determine whether or not it is on topic).

Comment: @Em. Unfortunately, I tried to find it back without success.

Answer (score 2):

It would make sense to ask a child for their school grade.  In the USA, grades go from 1-12 and are mostly (but not entirely) determined by age.

It doesn't make sense to ask an adult for their school grade.

It might make sense to ask an adult for the "highest level of education they have reached"  The answer would then be a word or description, eg "High School" or "Postgraduate degree".  It is possible that the survey may include a system for converting these descriptions to numbers for analysis.  But there is no universal system in use.

Translating between school systems is difficult, as different systems have different expectations.  For example in the UK, you can finish school at 16 at the end of year 11, or you can continue and do "advanced" education until year 13.  So the English and American systems are different.  And the Scottish systems are different again.  Grade 10 in the USA is the same as year 12 in Scotland.  The USA has four-year bachelor degrees and two year Master degrees.  England has three-year bachelor and one-year master degrees, but the English degree has a greater amount of specialisation from a younger age...  The French Baccalaureate is different again and doesn't correspond to anything in the US, English or Scottish system.

So if this is an important form (such as for a visa or job application) where you can lose out if the answer is "wrong" then you need to ask for guidance from the person who created the form.  If not then use your judgement.  "17" is probably wrong, but it is no more wrong than anything else.

Answer (score 1):

In the UK there is a system of ["qualification levels](https://www.reed.co.uk/career-advice/levels-of-education-what-do-they-mean/)", but it is not widely used outside of education:

Entry Level any qualification below level 1.
Level 1 Equivalent to a grade 1-3 at GCSE, a "failing" grade at GCSE.
Level 2 Equivalent to grade 4-9 at GCSE, a "passing" grade at GCSE, usually taken at age 16
Level 3 Equivalent to a passing grade A-E at A-level usually taken at age 18.
Level 4 Equivalent to the first year of a university degree.  HND or similar.
Level 5 Equivalent to the second and third year of university degree BA, BSC or similar.
Level 6 Equivalent to a Masters degree.  MA, MSc, MBA or similar.
Level 7 Equivalent to a doctorate.  PhD, or similar.